# Change markup in WooCommerce shortcode output

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, product

Is it possible to use a WooCommerce shortcode e.g. **`[product_category category="appliances"]`** amending the markup to include a **`<div>`** tag around some elements?

I know I can do this by duplicating what the shortcode does but that seems overkill just to add a wrapping **`<div>`**.

I could do it with jQuery but don't want any delay in them loading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **@Updated**

Yes this is absolutely possible. You can achieve this with something like that:

```
if( !function_exists('prod_cat') ) {

    function prod_cat( $atts ) {

        extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'cat'   => '',  // category
            'class' => '' // Optional adding class to <div> tag


        ), $atts));

        if ( $class != '') {
            $class = ' class="' . $class . '"';
        }

        return '<div'.$class.'>' . do_shortcode("[product_category category=" . $cat . "]") . '</div>';

    }

    add_shortcode('prod_cat', 'prod_cat');
}
```

*Paste the above code snippet in the function.php file of active child theme or theme*

**This code is tested and fully functional.**

---

**USAGE:**

You have 2 arguments for this the **`shortcode`**:

- `cat="your_category"` to set your category
- `class="your_div_class"` to set css classes to the **`<div>`** tag *(optional)*.

You can use it in any woocommerce page as any shortcode does:

```
[prod_cat cat="appliances" class="my_optional_div_class"]
```

Comment: Sorry but this wraps an overall <div> around the entire set of products, I am looking to put a containing <div> inside the <li> which is output for each product.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38932914/add-containing-div-inside-li-output-from-woocommerce-shortcode