# Add login form shortcode programatically to every published product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, product

I am running a wholesale shop on Woocommerce. Login is required to see the prices. This is set up and working properly. Now I wish to add a logon form on every product page to only show to visitors (not logged on users).

I am using the WooCommerce Catalog Visibility plugin. This plugin offers the functionality I described above, but my theme is somehow messing it up. The plugin author says to talk to the theme developer and the theme developer says to talk to the plugin author. So now I am trying to find a workaround.

---

**First issue:** The plugin comes with a shortcode [woocommerce_logon_form] that will display a logon form. I don't want to manually add this to every existing product since I have thousands of products on my site. I am looking for a way to get it in through the code for the product page layout.

I found this code (to be added to the functions.php) to work well:

```
// adds notice at single product page above add to cart


add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'return_policy', 20 );
function return_policy() {
    echo '<p id="rtrn">30-day return policy offered. See Terms and Conditions for details.</p>';
}
```

However, it will only show text. The short code won't work when added instead of the sample text.

**Second issue:** The short code shows the form even when the customer is already logged in.

I am currently using this nice code that shows or hides content depending on whether the user is logged in or not:

```
add_shortcode( 'access', 'access_check_shortcode' );

function access_check_shortcode( $attr, $content = null ) {

    extract( shortcode_atts( array( 'capability' => 'read' ), $attr ) );

    if ( current_user_can( $capability ) && !is_null( $content ) && !is_feed() )
        return $content;

    return '';
}

add_shortcode( 'visitor', 'visitor_check_shortcode' );

function visitor_check_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
     if ( ( !is_user_logged_in() && !is_null( $content ) ) || is_feed() )
        return $content;
    return '';
}
```

That shortcode works perfectly for text, but not with other shortcodes. 
So the combination of these short codes: [visitor][woocommerce_logon_form][/visitor] will not show the logon form to visitors. Instead it will only show them this as text [woocommerce_logon_form].

---

Please help! I am sure this is probably easily fixed by someone with coding skills. 
I appreciate your effort to answer to this question. Keep in mind that my understanding of code is very limited and it would be great if you can also point out in which file to add or modify code.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, many thanks for the detailed and clear answer!! I had quick look and I think this solves my both issues. I still need to test it but am a little busy at the moment. I will give you feedback of my test in a day or 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To make your shortcode working in php code or in php/html code you need to use a native [WordPress function **`do_shortcode()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) … You can use it with your shortcode for example in your 1st function this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'return_policy', 20 );
function return_policy() {
    echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_logon_form]');
}
```

And this will work…

To see all the different hooks you can use instead of **`woocommerce_single_product_summary`**, please see this 2 templates code to chose in case a more convenient hook:

- [WooCommerce single-product.php template](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/2.6.0/templates/single-product.php)
- [WooCommerce content-single-product.php template](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/2.6.0/templates/content-single-product.php)

---

You can also add it the same way in one of your existing short codes, this way:

```
add_shortcode( 'visitor', 'visitor_check_shortcode' );

function visitor_check_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    if ( ( !is_user_logged_in() && !is_null( $content ) ) || is_feed() )
        return do_shortcode('[woocommerce_logon_form]');
    return '';
}
```

And this will work too.

See as reference this answer: [Change markup in WooCommerce shortcode output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38803702/change-markup-in-woocommerce-shortcode-output/38804868#38804868)

---

> **So as you can see your problem is solved on both issues**